# Identifying the newly added element using CssSelector through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, katalon-studio

I have an element that gets different new css selector after adding its respective item, so each time I add an item on the page then this item gets added as the last record so how can I detect and catch it css selector?

```
WebElement changingselec = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > app > div > manage-corr-app > div > div.flex-5.work-area-large > manage-user-recipient-groups > div > div:nth-child(10)"));

changingselec.click();
```

Notice that `div:nth-child(10)` indicates that the last current record is the tenth record, if I add a new one then its selector will render this section to be `div:nth-child(11)`, so I cannot predict the correct selector of the targeted item.

Answer (score 1):

There is a :last-child selector in CSS. Try this

```
WebElement changingselec = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > app > div > manage-corr-app > div > div.flex-5.work-area-large > manage-user-recipient-groups > div > div:last-child"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase the newly added `<div>` is the *last child* of it's parent then @MateMrše solution is just perfect.

- Using `div:last-child`: Selects every `div` element that is the last child of its parent:

  ```
  WebElement changingselec = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > app > div > manage-corr-app > div > div.flex-5.work-area-large > manage-user-recipient-groups > div > div:last-child"));
  ```

Incase the newly added `<div>` is the *last child* of `<div>` type of it's parent then you need to:

- Use `div:last-of-type`: Selects every `<div>` element that is the last `<div>` element of its parent:

  ```
  WebElement changingselec = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > app > div > manage-corr-app > div > div.flex-5.work-area-large > manage-user-recipient-groups > div > div:last-of-type"));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for my question by my elder colleague at work as the following:

```
String changingselec = "";

int lastChildIndex = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("body > app > div > manage-corr-app > div > div.flex-5.work-area-large > manage-user-recipient-groups > div > div.panel")).size(); 

//I replaced the last section in the selector above > div:nth-child(10) by > div.panel because all elements share the same parent panel

changingselec = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > app > div > manage-corr-app > div > div.flex-5.work-area-large > manage-user-recipient-groups > div > div.panel:nth-child(" + Integer.toString(lastChildIndex) + ")")).click();
```

I hope this helps.